# Cauchy Sequence

Tags: real-analysis

Problem : Let $x_n $ be a sequence and supposed that exist $c\in (0, 1)$ such that for all $ n> n_0$  satisfied that $  | x_{n+1} |<c|x_n  |$. Show that  $ x_n \rightarrow 0$.

Find, $| x_{n+1}|<c^{n-n_0} |x_{n_0}|$. But I cant use in the Cauchy sequence, i. e.  $|x_m -x_n|$. Help me, please.

Comment: I am confused. So you want to use Cauchy sequence to prove the limit $0$?

Comment: I want use Cauchy because, if Cauchy then converge

Comment: It is going to be harder to prove that the sequence is Cauchy and therefore converges than it will be to prove that the sequence converges and is therefore Cauchy.

Comment: Help me with an HINT please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have
$x_n
<c^{n-1-n_0}|x_{n_0}|
=c^{n}c^{-1-n_0}|x_{n_0}|
=dc^{n}
$,
where
$d = c^{-1-n_0}|x_{n_0}|
$.

Since
$0 < c < 1$,
$c = \dfrac1{1+b}
$,
where
$b
=\dfrac1{c}-1 
$.

By Bernoulli's inequality,
$(1+b)^n
\ge 1+nb
\gt nb
$,
so
$c^n
= \dfrac1{(1+b)^n}
< \dfrac1{nb}
$
so that
$x_n
<dc^{n}
< \dfrac{d}{nb}
$.

Therefore
$x_n \to 0$.

If you want to use Cauchy,
if
$0 < m < n$,
then
$|x_n| < c^{n-m}|x_m|
< |x_m|
$,
so that

$\begin{array}\\
|x_m-x_n|
&\le |x_m|+|x_n|\\
&< 2|x_m|\\
&< 2\dfrac{d}{mb}\\
&\to 0 \text{ as } m \to \infty\\
\end{array}
$

Answer (score 0):

$|x_{n+1}| < c^{n-n_0}|x_{n_0}|$

Since $c<1,$
for some $N, c^{N-n_0}|x_{n_0}|<\epsilon$

$N = \frac {\ln {\epsilon} - \ln |x_{n_0}|}{\ln c} + n_0$

$n>N \implies |x_{n+1}|<\epsilon$

Comment: Would help me with a hint for  use Cauchy please.